# Obtain mean value of specific area in netCDF

Tags: python, time-series, mean, netcdf, python-xarray

I am trying to plot a time series of the sea surface temperature (SST) for a specific region from a .nc file. The SST is a three-dimensional variable (lat,lon,time), that has mean daily values for a specific region from 1982 to 2016. I want my plot to reflect the seasonal sst variability of the entire period of time. I assume that what I need to do first is to **obtain a mean sst value for my lat,lon region for each of the days** with which I can work alter on. So far, I assume that I need to read the .nc file and the variables:

```
import netCDF4 as nc

f = nc.Dataset('cmems_SST_MED_SST_L4_REP_OBSERVATIONS_010_021_1639073212518.nc')
sst = f.variables['analysed_sst'][:]
lon = f.variables['longitude'][:]
lat = f.variables['latitude'][:]
```

Next, following the code suggested [here](https://help.ceda.ac.uk/article/4728-cru-data-python-example), I tried to reshape and obtain the mean, but an error pops up:

```
global_average= np.nanmean(sst[:,:,:],axis=(1,2))
annual_temp = np.nanmean(np.reshape(global_average, (34,12)), axis = 1) 

#34 years between 1982 and 2016, and 12 months per year.
```

> **ERROR** cannot reshape array of size 14008 into shape (34,12)

From here I found different ways, like using cdo or nco (which didn't work due installation problems) among others, which were not suitable for my case. I used nanmean because know that in MATLAB this is done using the nanmean function. I am quite new to this topic and I would like to ask for some hints, like, where should I focus more or what path is more suitable for this case. Thank you!!

Comment: In the link that you sent, they use monthly data of 117 years. You use daily data. So you create a global average of temperature for each day. For some reason, you have 14,008 data points which is > 34*365 = 12,410. Without the dataset this is difficult to solve, but what you tried with the reshape can not work, as you don't have 34*12= 408 datapoints in your global_average dataset

Comment: You should find out more about the shape of the original dataset first and which datapoints are from which year.

Comment: Okat, thank you @steTATO , I will provide more details about the dataset shortly.

Comment: have you considered [xarray](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/index.html)? This would be `ds = xr.open_dataset(...)`, then `ds.groupby('time.season').mean(dim='time')`

Answer (score 0):

Handling daily data with just pure python is difficult because you should consider leap years and sub-setting a region require tedious indexing striding....

As steTATO mentioned, since the data that you are working has daily temporal resolution you need to consider the following

You need to reshape the `global_average` in the shape of (34,365) or (34,366) depending on the year (1984,1988,1992,1996,2000,2004,2008,2012,2016). So your above code should look something like

```
annual_temp = np.nanmean(np.reshape(global_average, (34,365)), axis = 1)
```

But, like I said, because of the leap years, you can't do the things you want by simply reshaping the `global_average`.

If I had no choice but to use python only, I'd do the following

```
import numpy as np

def days_in_year(in_year):
   leap_years = [1984,1988,1992,1996,2000,2004,2008,2012,2016]
   if (in_year in leap_years):
      out_days = 366
   else:
      out_days = 365

   return out_days


# some of your code, importing netcdf data

year = np.arange(1982,2017)

global_avg= np.nanmean(sst[:,:,:],axis=(1,2))

annual_avgs = []
i = 0
for yr in range(35):
   i  =  i + days_in_year(year[yr])
   f  =  i - days_in_year(year[yr])

   annual_avg  =  np.nanmean(global_avg[i:f])
   annual_avgs.append(annual_avg)
```

Above code basically takes and averages by taking strides of the `global_avg` considering the leap year, and saving it as `annual_avgs`.